# Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - But the numbers are the same

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I've seen similar questions, but I don't seem to be missing a comma or anything, and TEXT is the value that corresponds with the database column.

I'm expecting to be able to submit a log consisting of text into my table, but I get the 1136 error instead. Removing the personal_log and (text) works fine, on submit I get an automated timestamp in the personal_log_date column and a NULL in the log column.

I'm very new to all of this and have read through some documentation, and it looks like TEXT should be accepted as a value.

Thanks for any knowledge you can drop on me!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `personal_log`(`personal_log_date`,`personal_log`) 
            VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),(TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tries to insert 2 rows with 1 column:

```
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),(TEXT)
```

But you want to insert 1 row with 2 columns:

```
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, TEXT)
```

Comment: I see! Thank you for your helpful explanation.